# definition of an infinite descending chain

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Given a set with a partial order $\leq$, can we say that the following is an infinite descending chain?

$a\geq\cdots a_{-2}\geq a_{-1}\geq a_{0}\geq a_1\geq a_{2}\cdots$

I am confused because I have normally seen infinite descending chains indexed by the set of natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$ not by the set of integers, $\mathbb{Z}$ as above.

Comment: Yes. Technically, you *can* use any countable set to index an infinite descending chain. *Most* authors will use the set of natural numbers instead, because it makes the intended order more obvious.

Comment: I recally making this kind of speculation when I was learning some basic facts about noetherian topological spaces, and I decided that the notion is liked best was "A weakly decreasing function from an ordinal (i.e. totally ordered set) to the ordered set of interest". I did not like the fact that total orders had "two cofinalities" in that instance.

Comment: However, in set theory one usually refers to "chains" as totally ordered subsets of patial orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is an index set, with linear order $<_I$ and we have $a_i \in (X,\le_X)$ for all $i \in I$ then we have a decreasing chain $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ iff

$$\forall i,j \in I: (i \le_I j) \implies a_i \ge_X a_j$$

so that larger-indexed elements are smaller. So under that definition, yes you have a decreasing chain, though the first element has no index, BTW and if you index by $\Bbb Z$ we will have no first-indexed element of cours, so leave it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: While one can define whatever one wants, note that the definition proposed here is at odds with the usual notion of ascending and descending chains as used for instance in the [ascending chain condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) in algebra, where chains are implicitly assumed to always be indexed by the natural numbers (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_descending_chain and note that "chain" and "sequence" are used without distinction). Notably $\Bbb N$ is supposed to not allow infinite strictly decreasing chains, but would with this definition.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen only if you allow index sets with a maximum which would be unusual.

Comment: Allowing index sets with a maximum is quite normal, especially when they are finite. Indeed, if not having a maximum were implicitly assumed for any index set, I see no point to saying "infinite" in "infinite descending chain". It seems more plausible to assume that, in the context of ascending of descending chains, index sets (finite or not) are always implicitly assumed to be well ordered, rather than have no maximum. (There could be amusing notions of such chains indexed by specific kinds of ordinals, even though I cannot say having aver seen them in practice.)